# Desabilitar opção se não tiver com o Javascript habilitado?

Tags: javascript

Estou usando uma tag que verifica se o Javascript está habilitado, caso ele não esteja, gostaria que uma opção na tela ficasse invisível. Como poderia chamar uma função caso isso ocorra?
agradeço

```
<noscript>
    Para completa funcionalidade deste site é necessário habilitar o JavaScript.
    Aqui estão as <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/pt/" target="_blank">
    instruções de como habilitar o JavaScript no seu navegador</a>.
</noscript>
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você disse, quer que quando ele habilite o JavaScript a página passe a executar as funções sem precisar o usuário fazer o refresh? É isso?

Comment: Quero que se o javascript estiver desativado, quero deixar botão invisivelmente até o mesmo ativar novamente o javascript

Comment: Cara, acho que te entenderam errado. Eu entendi que você quer por exemplo sumir com um botao/div etc se o cara não tiver o JavaScript habilitado, é isso? Se for, o qie eu faria é deixar o elemento já oculto com CSS (display: none), e mostrar ele com JavaScript assim que carregar a pagina. Desse jeito se o cara tiver o JavaScript desabilitado essa função nunca vai ser chamada e o botao vai continuar oculto.

Comment: @user7349055, correto, você foi o único que entendeu bem a questão, eu precisava de um exemplo prático

Answer (score 3):

Não tem como sumir com o conteudo do `<noscript>` quando o usuário habilitar o JavaScript, será necessário fazer o refresh, e isso **só o usuário poderá fazer**, não tem de forma alguma como contornar isto, a não ser talvez usar o meta=refresh para ficar recarregando a página até que o usuário habilite o JavaScript, por exemplo:

```html
<noscript>
<!-- faz o refresh de 10 em 10 até que o usuário reabilite o cache -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">

Para completa funcionalidade deste site é necessário habilitar o JavaScript.
Aqui estão as <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/pt/" target="_blank">
instruções de como habilitar o JavaScript no seu navegador</a>.
</noscript>
```

Um dos motivos para isso é porque os navegadores tem um ciclo de execução em inserção ("importação") do JavaScript, por exemplo, se pudesse executar uma função apenas da pessoa habilitar o JavaScript então funções como:

```
document.write
```

Iriam falhar ou sobre-escrever a página toda, pois este tipo de funções precisa ser executada conforme o "fluxo" de renderização do DOM (da página), então por isso que é necessário recarregar a página toda, para que o comportamento seja o esperado conforme a renderização.

### Navegadores ainda vem com o JavaScript desabilitado?

Quero que entenda uma coisa, é praticamente impossível um usuário desabilitar o JavaScript, isso ocorria na época no IE 4, 5 e NetScape 4, pois na época o JavaScript não vinha habilitado por padrão (se eu não me engano), agora realmente nos dias hoje é improvável que o usuário navegue nos sites sem JavaScript, é raríssimo um site que não dependa de tal tecnologia, então o usuário simplesmente não conseguiria navegar em nada.

Se existem algum motivo para o usuário ter desabilitado com toda certeza foi intencional, ou seja mesmo que você coloque as instruções para habilitar ele provavelmente sabe como fazer e sabe que terá que dar o refresh (F5, Ctrl+R, etc).

Então se preocupar com algo assim nos dias de hoje realmente é algo desnecessário, pois se o usuário não quer usar javascript habilitado, provavelmente ele sabe o que é javascript e tem uma motivação muito boa e pessoal e provavelmente ele vai habilitar o javascript quando necessário, claro que você pode deixar a mensagem, mas pode ter certeza, que se ele sabe desabilitar ele também saberá habilitar e saberá dar o refresh após isso.

Comment: No celular da samsung, usuário pode desativar javascript facilmente, indo na opção de menu e desativar.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda se ele foi até isso é porque ele quis e por um otimo motivo pessoal, se ele sabe fazer isso, também saberá que é necessário o refresh. Eu expliquei isso na resposta: *"Se existem algum motivo para o usuário ter desabilitado com toda certeza foi intencional"*.